Adsorption energy calculations using quantum espresso through BURAI
I'm currently working on a CO2 capture project and would love some guidance as I'm not super confident about what I'm doing and am in sore need of some mentorship. I want to test different zeolite surfaces with different conditions like Si/Al ratio, extra framework cations, and pressure conditions. I want to evaluate their CO2 selectivity and capacity. I also plan to use pressure swing adsorption so I'd also like to find optimal pressures for adsorption and desorption. To do this, I plan to use BURAI which is a GUI for quantum espresso. I understand that for a DFT simulation,

Adsorption energy = energy of surface and CO2 - energy of surface - energy of CO2

However, I believe DFT implies absolute 0, which would give me inaccurate results as pressure and temperature conditions affect the functionality of zeolites during adsorption. So I plan on using MD simulation, where I can select a specific pressure. Now what I want to do is try different pressures to see where the optimal pressure for each surface is, this should give me the CO2 selectivity as well as the pressure conditions. My main question is:
Is MD simulation appropriate for my needs?
I apologize for the long post, if there's anything I'm doing that doesn't make sense or is incorrect, I would greatly appreciate you pointing it out. Thank you.

+1 and welcome to our community! However if you rollback one more time there will be diamond moderator intervention. One question is permitted per post.

Oh, I apologize, I was confused as to why my question was edited. I just have many questions and didn't realize that was a rule.

One of the reasons for closing a question is more than one question being asked.
